# Best way to fill in this blank spaces

Tags: r

using data from  http://statland.org/AP/R/heartatk4R.txt

I read the data as follows:

```
heartatk4R <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\"heartatk4R.txt",         
            header = TRUE, sep = "\t",          
            colClasses = c("character", "factor", "factor", "factor", 
                           "factor", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
head(heartatk4R)
```

I want to Calculate the average cost per day for patients with different DIAGNOSIS codes. Restrict to females aged older than 20 and younger than 70 who stayed at least one day.Sort the results in descending order

In this is not running based on my questions: any help

```
library(dplyr)
df <- heartatk4R%>%
filter (SEX=="F"& AGE >20 & AGE < 70 & DRG >== )%>%
  group_by(heartatk4R)%>%
  arrange (CostPerDay = CHARGES)%>%
  summarise(AvgCostPERDAY = (CostPerDay, na.rm = _))%>%
  (-AvgCostPerDay)
df
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *Calculate the average cost per day* with `aggregate` like:

```
heartatk4R <- read.table("http://statland.org/AP/R/heartatk4R.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", colClasses = c("character", "factor", "factor", "factor","factor", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"), na.strings = "*")

tt <- with(heartatk4R[heartatk4R$SEX=="F" & heartatk4R$AGE>20 & heartatk4R$AGE<70,],
 aggregate(data.frame(CostPerDay = CHARGES), data.frame(DIAGNOSIS), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE))
tt[order(-tt[,2]),]
#  DIAGNOSIS CostPerDay
#1     41001  11911.179
#3     41021  11165.837
#2     41011  10922.091
#5     41041  10366.557
#4     41031  10101.536
#8     41081   9641.175
#7     41071   9558.745
#9     41091   9528.740
#6     41051   9393.048
```

I don't know where to see if a person *stayed at least one day*?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we could `filter` the values, `group_by` `DIAGNOSIS` and take `mean` of `CHARGES`

```
heartatk4R <- read.csv(url("http://statland.org/AP/R/heartatk4R.txt"), sep = "\t")

library(dplyr)

heartatk4R %>%
   filter(SEX == "F" & AGE > 20 & AGE < 70) %>%
   mutate(CHARGES = as.numeric(as.character(CHARGES))) %>%
   group_by(DIAGNOSIS) %>%
   summarise(AvgCostPERDAY  = mean(CHARGES, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   arrange(desc(AvgCostPERDAY))

# DIAGNOSIS AvgCostPERDAY
#      <int>         <dbl>
#1     41001        11911.
#2     41021        11166.
#3     41011        10922.
#4     41041        10367.
#5     41031        10102.
#6     41081         9641.
#7     41071         9559.
#8     41091         9529.
#9     41051         9393.
```